# How to convert this REPLACE INTO statement into its equivalent UPDATE statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have the following MySQL statement using `REPLACE INTO`:

```
 INSERT INTO `tableX`.latest_status (tableX_id, name, nick)
 (
     SELECT records.id,
            records.name,
            records.nick
     FROM `tableX`.records records
     WHERE (`records`.`time` = 0)
 )
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=tableX.name, nick=tableX.nick
```

Due to some bug created, I realized `REPLACE INTO` is not suitable for my app. What I want is to update existing rows. If the row does not exist, do nothing. I guess UPDATE should be the right clause to use. Am I right at this point?

I tried to convert the above MySQL statement into the equivalent one using `UPDATE`. Here is the code;

```
UPDATE `tableX`.latest_status
SET tableX_id, name, nick =
(
     SELECT records.id,
            records.name,
            records.nick
     FROM `tableX`.records records
     WHERE (`records`.`time` = 0)
)
```

Unfortunately, there are some syntax errors at the `SET tableX_id, name, nick`. How should the equivalent UPDATE statement look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idont know if i get what you want but this is something may help you (I think you can do something like it with your tables)

```
UPDATE patient
SET full_name=(
     SELECT full_name
     FROM staff
     WHERE staff.id=patient.id
)
,national_number =
(
     SELECT national_number
     FROM staff
     WHERE staff.id=patient.id
)
```

Comment: Although your answer looks long-winded and inefficient, it is at least easier for a newbie like me to understand. I tried it and things worked. So, I chose it as the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: thank you i'm also a newbie so i know how hard is to find an easy answer

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is off - you can't write a query anything like that.

Try updating via a join:

```
UPDATE tableX.latest_status s
JOIN tableX.records r
  ON id = tableX_id
  AND r.name = s.name
  AND time = 0
SET s.nick = r.nick
```

Comment: I think your answer is correct but I do not know how to translate it to my code. The fault is mine as I am not good enough. The other answer from Moneer Kamal is not efficient but at least easier to understand for me. I got things working using his answer. So, I am going to vote his answer as the right answer. Sorry.

Comment: That's OK. If the other answer worked better for you then it can work better for someone else too. Don't ever feel pressured to vote - just vote naturally. Happy coding.